# Word List compression

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I'm working on a compression algorithm for a string (containing a list of comma seperated words). The result will be a string formated like 'word-count'. 
Eg: 'a, a, b, c'-> 'a-2, b-1, c-1'

Not sure why this isn't working

```
def word_compression(words):
    words=words.split(",")
    print(words)
    prev=words[0]
    count=0
    #record=dict()
    s=""
    for i in range (len(words)):
        word=words[i].strip()
        if(word==prev):
            count+=1
            print(word,count)
        else:
            #new word
            #record[prev]=count
            print(word,prev)
            if(s==""):
                s=prev+"-"+str(count)
            else:
                s=s+", "+prev+"-"+str(count)
            print("changed from: ",prev, word)
            count=1
            prev=word

    print(prev,count)
    s=s+", "+prev+"-"+str(count)
    return s
```

Comment: check [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html)

Comment: @FrainBr33z3 Counting words is not the same thing as doing run-length encoding.

Comment: General tip: *"Not sure why this isn't working"* - Learn how to use the debugger in your IDE. If you're not using an IDE, pick one. Go through your program with the debugger to figure out why it does not do what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer a solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get the counts, then use `', '.join` to join the results:

```
from itertools import groupby
from re import split

def word_compression(words):
    words = split(r',\s*', words)
    counts = (f'{word}-{sum(1 for _ in group)}' for word, group in groupby(words))
    return ', '.join(counts)

print(word_compression("1,1,1,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1"))
# 1-6, 2-4, 3-2, 1-3
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Do you think help me understand my thing doesn't work? I've been struggling with it.

Comment: @pasha One problem I noticed was that you always add `', '` to your string, so if you only have one word in your list it looks like `', a-2'`

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
l = ["a", "a", "b", "c"]

def my_histogram(l):
    res = {}
    for i in l:
        if i in res:
            res[i] += 1
        else:
            res[i] = 1
    return(res)

want = my_histogram(l)

print([k + "->" + str(v) for k, v in want.items()])

# ['a->2', 'b->1', 'c->1']
```